# determine which key is pressed

Tags: javascript

How to determine which key is pressed in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

in the function which takes the key event:

```
function(e){
   var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).live('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  //do stuff with keycode
  } 
});
```

Normal:

```
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       

function KeyCheck(){

   var KeyID = event.keyCode;
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `keydown` and `keyup` events on the `document` and set a flag for each key.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
function myKeyPress(e){
    var keynum;
    if(window.event){ // IE
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    }else
    if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
    alert(keynum);
    if (keynum == 13) {
        alert("You Pressed Enter Key");
    }
}
```

In HTML:

```
<textarea name="box" id="box" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)"></textarea>
```